# "Cpr" C++ request library returning internal error

Tags: c++, httpresponse

I wrote a get request code in [cpr library](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr)  and I sent a get request to this [url](http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA) but its returning an internal error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA"});
    int infosf = r.status_code;
    std::cout << infosf;
    return 0;
}
```

headers loaded fine but its returning internal error

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\curl_container.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\payload.h:6,                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h:16,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\cpr.h:4,                 from .\meantest.cpp:4:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\curlholder.h:22:17: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type     static std::mutex curl_easy_init_mutex_;
                 ^~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\cpr.h:4:0,
                 from .\meantest.cpp:4:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h: In function 'cpr::AsyncResponse cpr::GetAsync(Ts ...)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h:45:32: error: return type 'using AsyncResponse = class std::future<cpr::Response> {aka class std::future<cpr::Response>}' is incomplete
 AsyncResponse GetAsync(Ts... ts) {
                                ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h: In function 'cpr::AsyncResponse cpr::PostAsync(Ts ...)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h:69:33: error: return type 'using AsyncResponse = class std::future<cpr::Response> {aka class std::future<cpr::Response>}' is incomplete
 AsyncResponse PostAsync(Ts... ts) {
                                 ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h: In function 'cpr::AsyncResponse cpr::PutAsync(Ts ...)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h:93:32: error: return type 'using AsyncResponse = class std::future<cpr::Response> {aka class std::future<cpr::Response>}' is incomplete
 AsyncResponse PutAsync(Ts... ts) {
                                ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h: In function 'cpr::AsyncResponse cpr::HeadAsync(Ts ...)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h:117:33: error: return type 'using AsyncResponse = class std::future<cpr::Response> {aka class std::future<cpr::Resture<cpr::Response> {aka class std::future<cpr::Response>}' is incomplete
 AsyncResponse OptionsAsync(Ts... ts) {
                                    ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h: In function 'cpr::AsyncResponse cpr::PatchAsync(Ts ...)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\cpr\api.h:192:34: error: return type 'using AsyncResponse = class std::future<cpr::Response> {aka class std::future<cpr::Response>}' is incomplete
 AsyncResponse PatchAsync(Ts... ts) {
```

I tried turning off firewall still it didnt work

Comment: Are you compiling on a `C++11` Standard compliant compiler (or greater)? What command are you using to compile this?

Comment: I think this is a problem with mingw compiler that can't compile that line of code in cpr library. could you try compiling this 
`#include <mutex>
static std::mutex curl_easy_init_mutex_;
int main() {
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @Galik I use g++ -Wall main.cpp to run and I use c++ 17

Comment: @MohamedKandeel but its showing std has no member mutex even though I included mutex

Comment: For `C++17` you need to compile with the command `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall main.cpp`.

Comment: If the problem was in the C++ version it would give an error of "mutex header not found". What i suspect as i told you is that there is a problem with the mingw compiler itself. try to make a minimal reproducible program to know where exactly the error. as I mentioned above.

Comment: @yeah It was problem of mingw compiler in windows.